# Placeholder text alignment in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I don't know how to top the placeholder text in a entry box.
I have a entry box that is very big and want to put the placeholder text in the top.

```
<Entry Placeholder="Enter notes about the item" 
       Keyboard="Text" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="80" />
```

Comment: Please add some code / layout (what you tried until now) and describe exactly what you want. Otherwise it's almost impossible to help

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create a custom renderer for each platform to aling the placeholder something like this:

```
public class PlaceholderEditor : Editor
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceholderProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<PlaceholderEditor, string>(view => view.Placeholder, String.Empty);

    public PlaceholderEditor()
    {
    }

    public string Placeholder
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(PlaceholderProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value);
        }
    }
}

public class PlaceholderEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
{
    public PlaceholderEditorRenderer()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(
        ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var element = e.NewElement as PlaceholderEditor;
            this.Control.Hint = element.Placeholder;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(
        object sender,
        PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == PlaceholderEditor.PlaceholderProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            var element = this.Element as PlaceholderEditor;
            this.Control.Hint = element.Placeholder;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working fine in android renderer. But this.Control.Hint is not found in iOS rebderer!!!

Comment: To do the iOS renderer the code will be different, please refer to this page: https://github.com/jimbobbennett/JimLib.Xamarin/blob/master/JimLib.Xamarin.ios/Controls/ExtendedEntryRenderer.cs

Answer (score -1):

No need more Customize, only need use in XAML: `HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"`