# xamrin cross Platform cursor by default from right to left in Editor

Tags: xamarin, cursor, editor, cross-platform, right-to-left

I'm using cross Platform.

how can I put the cursor by default from right to left in a Editor.

Thanks,

Batch

Comment: By cursor, do you mean the writing direction?

Comment: no, its writing from right to left but before you begin to writing then cursor is in the left side and I nead  the cursor will be in the right side

Comment: Still missing a lot in the question to make a good answer. Which Editor are you talking about? What you are looking for is changing the text alignment guess?

Comment: normal  editor. i mean the if the focus is on the editor so the cursor will be on the right side

Comment: `<Editor HeightRequest="150"  VerticalOptions="End" TextChanged="CommentsEditorTextChanged"   x:Name="CommentsEditor"  Text="{Binding Comments,Mode=TwoWay}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a custom renderer to achieve that.

You can find some useful tips on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778337/placeholder-text-alignment-in-xamarin-forms) and [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42438/align-center-text-entry).